# option tag wouldn't get appended in select tag when using Bootstrap's list-group css class

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, select

/webresources/university/autocomplete (JSON webservice):

```js
[{"fullName":"FACULTÉ DES SCIENCES TECHNIQUES DE TANGER","id":1,"name":"FST TANGER"},{"fullName":"ECOLE NATIONALE DES SCIENCES APPLIQUÉES DE TÉTOUAN","id":2,"name":"ENSA TETOUAN"}]
```

```js
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: '/webresources/university/autocomplete',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',

    success: function (response) {
        var items = [];
        
        $.each(response, function (i,item) {
                items.push('<option>' + item.fullName + '</option>'); 
            });
                        
            $('#List-Group-University').append(items);
            alert(items[0])
        }
    });
</script>
```

```html
<select  id="List-Group-University" class="list-group" multiple>
        <option>bla bla</option>
        <option>bli bli</option>
</select>
```

option tag wouldn't get appended in select tag when using Bootstrap's list-group css class.
Appending works if I remove 'class="list-group"'.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for..can you provide more detail on what you would like answered.

Comment: i would like to append the webservice results to the select tag

Comment: Deleted my answer because I was wrong. Missed the list-group part.

Comment: alright thanks anyway ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has something to do with bootstrap interfering. I've setup a fiddle which shows both bootstrap list and non-bootstrap list. It seems to work okay, can it be a problem with the json setup?

http://jsfiddle.net/2yaphLx7/4/

HTML

```
<select id="List-Group-University" multiple>
    <option>bla bla</option>
    <option>bli bli</option>
</select>

<select id="List-Group-University-BS" class="list-group" multiple>
    <option>bla bla</option>
    <option>bli bli</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var response = [{
    "fullName": "FACULTÉ DES SCIENCES TECHNIQUES DE TANGER",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "FST TANGER"
}, {
    "fullName": "ECOLE NATIONALE DES SCIENCES APPLIQUÉES DE TÉTOUAN",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "ENSA TETOUAN"
}];

var items = [];
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
    items.push('<option>' + item.fullName + '</option>');
});

$('#List-Group-University').append(items);
$('#List-Group-University-BS').append(items);
```